# Unable to create container with a forward slash in Azure

Tags: c#, azure

I'm unable to create a container in Azure that contains a forward slash (I've also tried backslash) using the below code. Creating a container with no slash works.

The name of the container complies with azure rules. It's between the min and max length for container names, is lowercase and so on. I receive a generic response from Azure '400: bad request'

```
var exampleDirectory = "example/directory";
var cloudStorage = new CloudStorageAndDBConnections();
var blobClient = cloudStorage.blobClient;
var exampleContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(exampleDirectory ).CreateIfNotExists();
```

attempting this with "exampledirectory" instead of "example/directory" works.

I've read documentation that state a forward slash is allowed, so I'm lost..

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer assumes this is to build up urls to the blobs.

This is by design. The container name will always be at the root of any url.

You don't need to fill in the forward slash - azure will do that for you. So if your container had the following blobs:

- exampleblob.txt
- examplesub/exampleblob.txt
- examplesub/examplesub/exampleblob.txt

If you container name is ***exampledirectory***, they will resolve to the following urls:

- exampleblobservice.blob.core.windows.net/***exampledirectory***/exampleblob.txt
- exampleblobservice.blob.core.windows.net/***exampledirectory***/examplesub/exampleblob.txt
- exampleblobservice.blob.core.windows.net/***exampledirectory***/examplesub/examplesub/exampleblob.txt

So the blob service fills in the forward slash automatically

Answer (score 5):

Your container name is invalid, as container names may not contain a slash (`/`) character. Slashes are only allowed in blob names. Specifically, for container names (per the rules, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/naming-and-referencing-containers--blobs--and-metadata)):

- Container names must start with a letter or number, and ***can contain only letters, numbers, and the dash (-) character.***
- Every dash (-) character must be immediately preceded and followed by a letter or number; consecutive dashes are not permitted in container names.
- All letters in a container name must be lowercase.
- Container names must be from 3 through 63 characters long.

Comment: Ah, thank you - I think I must have got confused between container and blob.

Answer (score 2):

The concept of "directories" does not exist in Azure Storage. You create a container and upload files there.

If you want to create a "directory" structure, add the "path" to the file name. It will be generated automatically because what you store are files and paths.

You can then request the file with the url structure you created.

```
var exampleDirectory = "example";
var cloudStorage = new CloudStorageAndDBConnections();
var blobClient = cloudStorage.blobClient;
var exampleContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(exampleDirectory ).CreateIfNotExists();
var fileBase = exampleContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("directory/myfile.extension");
await fileBase.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream);
var myUrlWithForwardSlashes = fileBase.Uri.ToString();
```